# Django best practice when we automatically want to set the username

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-validation

In my webapp I want to automatically set the username field of a Django user using its email address. Currently I do it in the view before calling the *is_valid()* method of my form. But shouldn't I rather doing in in the *clean()* method of the form?

My form:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class DjangoUserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    required_css_class = 'required-field'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DjangoUserCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Making fields required
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['last_name'].required = True
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['password1'].required = True
        self.fields['password2'].required = True

    class Meta:
        model = DjangoUser
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Here is the view:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    ...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_form = DjangoUserForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            # In our system the email is also the username
            user.username = user_form.cleaned_data['email']
            user.save()
        ...
```

Comment: Is the username exactly same as email or you are processing the email beforehand? Can you add your implementation as well?

Comment: That looks quite opinion-based. Although `clean` method(s) is the best place for such things, there could be situations where you should do this at view level.

Comment: Why not use something like Django Auth tools which will allow you to use the email as the username?

Comment: @Johan this is interesting even if I'd like to avoid installing a Django app only to do this little thing :-)

Comment: If it saves you time, then it doesn't matter how many apps you use, even if you don't use all its features.